# Two wheeled self balancing robot(TWSBR)

Tags: gazebo, ros2-controllers, gazebo-ros2-control

I'm trying to impliment LQR in a TWSBR, the the control input is in terms of torque for the left and right wheels. Is there a way to use diff-drive controller for this? How do i convert torque to velocity?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to RSE.

No, you can't convert torque to velocity.
You have to formulate your system equations without wheel torque, but directly from linear acceleration (linear or angular accelartion from your wheel times wheel radius; for example [Eq 2 here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9735004) with $\ddot x$ as system input) and use this as system input for your LQR design. This means that you are neglecting the dynamics of the wheels and the linear motion.

Then you integrate the acceleration in time and use this as output for your hardware/gazebo_ros2_control.

I'm not sure if you should use diff_drive_controller here, or write a custom ros2_controller where the LQR control law is inside the controller. (depends on the dynamics and real-time requirement, you cannot guarantee this with a spinning node calculating velocity outputs and send this via topic to a ros2_controller).

If you stay in simulation anyways, you could also directly use the torque from your initial LQR design and use an [effort controller](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_controllers/effort_controllers/doc/userdoc.html) with gazebo_ros2_control. You just can't use this with every hardware, because you certainly won't have an effort interface.

Comment: I updated my answer, because in gazebo classic passive joints do work with velocity interface, only the position interface does not work.